# Are Porter Cable 20v and 20v Max batteries interchangeable?

Tags: drill

I have this drill and batteries and am wondering if it would fit a [PORTER-CABLE 20V MAX Random Orbital Sander](https://amzn.to/36jA2AD).

[image]

Comment: A general rule in these cases is that if the connectors fit, it is at least safe to connect them.

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to check your battery model against page 8 of the [compatibility chart](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/e6/e60c2de4-7983-4227-91b9-c394cdfefad9.pdf).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The statement by Porter Cable on the web page states that it "...will work with all PC 20 volt batteries". So you're good to go.

Comment: Are you referring to this [comment response](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/Tx1I1JV5E44FM18/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza)?

Comment: The batteries I have PCC681L also fit this https://amzn.to/3alKXuP.  Thanks for the great tips!